# search string form multiple column in database table

Tags: php, mysql, database, string

In my code i want to search the friends by its firstname , lastname and by a email fields. 
Now i want to match the exact string from the database table fields name.also i want to display that fields.also i want get the search data`s id so then after i will display the full description about that person.how can i do it.
thanks any help for me.
i try it.

```
$term=$_POST['find'];
$searchquery=mysql_query("select firstname,lastname,email from account where output LIKE %$term%");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for :

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email
FROM account
WHERE firstname LIKE %$term%
OR lastname LIKE %$term%
OR email LIKE %$term%
LIMIT 20
```

Note that your way is potentially dangerous, you should protect your `$term` variable :

```
$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['find']);
```

Anso note that mysql_* family function is under deprecation process, you should have a look to PDO or mysqli.

*Edit:*

Added a LIMIT because I don't think you want to recover all your database table if `$term` contains nothing.

Comment: ok bro its good but how can i display that fields and how to identified which fields is match from database.

Comment: i am display using this type is it give me error.pls check it

Comment: $resultsearch=mysql_query($searchquery);
 while($searchdata=mysql_fetch_array($resultsearch))
 {?>
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"   align="center">
     <tr>
        <td>
            <?php
   echo $searchdata['firstname'];
   echo $searchdata['lastname'];
   echo $searchdata['email'];
   ?>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   
 <?php }
 }
 
 ?>

Comment: Your mistake is here : `<?php } } ?>` : remove one brace `}`, you opened only one brace with `while(){` and no more.

Comment: is this line sqlinjection free or not?$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['find']);

Comment: it is.. that's not as safe as a prepared statement but that's quite fine.

Answer (score 1):

the query should be like this

```
$searchquery=mysql_query("select id,firstname,lastname,email from account where firstname LIKE '%$term%' OR lastname LIKE '%$term%' OR email LIKE '%$term%'");
```

if you want to search in either these 3 column(firstname,lastname,email).

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to fetch all the needed info you want to display, and to check in your wherestatement against the term. Like this:

```
select id, firstname, lastname, email /*, ... other fields */ from account where firstname LIKE '%$term%' OR lastname LIKE '%$term%' OR email LIKE '%$term%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select firstname,lastname,email from account where concat_ws(' ',firstname,lastname,email) LIKE %$term%"
```

will treat all three fields like single field and result will be faster

Comment: fistname barjo lastname hnick, looking for john will match? if that's really faster why not actually, using concat_ws perhaps. I'll test it thanks for the tip.